# How to set up LocalDb for unit tests in Visual Studio 2012 and Entity Framework 5

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, localdb

We have a Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET MVC project using Entity Framework 5.

There are some unit tests that depend on a database. Setting up the app.config file in the test project to use a central SQL Server database works fine.

However, it would be much nicer to use a LocalDb, so that each developer has his/her own database when running the tests. Especially since we would like to have the tests set up to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` when running.

However, I can't get the setup to work. If I try this in app.config:

```xml
<add name="TestDb" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=unittestdb;
     Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\unittestdb.mdf"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A file activation error occurred.
>   The physical file name '\unittestdb.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose
>   and correct additional errors, and retry the operation. CREATE
>   DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
>   related errors.

It sounds like it wants the mdf file to exist already, which seems strange since it is trying to create the database. Creating a mdf file manually does not change the error message.

Comment: Can you check what value do you have in unit test when you call: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")`?

Comment: The value of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")` in the unit test is `null`.

Comment: So either set the value to some path by using `SetData` or don't use `|DataDirectory|` in the connection string because it is `null`.

Comment: Removing the `|DataDirecotry|\` part does not help, I get the same error. However, replacing it with `C:\Temp\` does help! Then the unit tests run again. So that is a great improvement. Icing on the cake would be if the db could reside in a relative path.

Comment: I succeeded in getting a relative path after following the advice on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125157/relative-path-reference-in-webconfig-connectionstring)

Comment: Since you've found a solution, can you answer your own question and accept the answer?

Comment: NOTE: It may be safer to use (Localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB - that way tests won't break even if say SQL Express with localDB 2014 was installed (v12) vs SQL Express 2012 (v11)

Answer (score 34):

Try:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(
  "DataDirectory", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ""));
```

This will Create Db File on /bin/Debug/yourdbname.mdf

Answer (score 10):

I would use:

```
// Declare this property - this is set by MSTest
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

// In test initialization - note the signature should be exactly this
// A static void method with one argument of type TestContext 
[ClassInitialize]
public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
{
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.Combine(context.TestDeploymentDir, string.Empty));
}
```

You could get problems using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, instead use: `context.TestDeploymentDir`

Comment: What type is `context` and where does it come from?

Comment: Add a property like this one to your test class and MSTest will inject that for you `public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }`

Comment: Can you explain why doing this in a setup method is better than just before my `new Migrations.Configuration();`?

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that for a test project:

```
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|
```

means it will look in your output /bin/debug folder for a unit test as opposed to the App_Data folder in your web/production/whatever app.

You need to do two things
1. Move the database file OUT OF your App_Data folder to your root of your test app.
2. Highlight your database so you get your properties window in Visual Studio. Set the build action to "Content" so it will get copied to your output folder when you run the project.

Voila.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use this code (based on the answer of [Jupaol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297953/209727)):

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(
        "DataDirectory", 
        context.TestDeploymentDir);
}
```

Usually this will create your database inside `TestResults\<test run>\Out\` folder of your solution.

Comment: Hi, Using VS 2013 this code works when I run my unit test in "Debug Tests" mode. But it fails when I run "Run All" tests. How can I make it work in "Run All" mode

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while searching for answer to the problem. 
Using EntityFramework with nUnit in a separate project, I had to change the App.config

looked like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: And that worked for UnitTest using the DataSource Attribute?