# Generate test database for integration tests

Tags: ef-code-first, integration-testing

Code First Entity Framework can generate a database no trouble. Is there a way of parameterising the generation process such that I can create a fresh database instance just for integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the same database name but creating a new folder named after the current date by setting the 'DataDirectory'on the AppDomain. EF creates a SQL Server LocalDb with each test run.

Helped by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244495/how-to-set-up-localdb-for-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-and-entity-framework) answer.