# Database.Delete() throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework

When I use a relative path (AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;) in my connection string  Database.Delete() gives me

*InvalidOperationException : Unable to delete the database. There is no database that corresponds to the given AttachDBFileName.*

When using an absolute path deleting works. I know that my relative path is correct because other database operations work with it too.

I thought not being able to use a relative path with super directories (\..\) was the only limitation?

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.1 and LocalDB.

Comment: It's funny because the documentation says: "deletes if it exists, otherwise does nothing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14680912/210336) solved the problem for me:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ""));
```