# Using a relative path in connection string for Access DB in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string, relative-path

I'm trying to get this line in my web.config file to use a relative path instead of hardcoded one, but nothing seems to be working. I can only find stuff for SQL and mySQL DBs

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\GeauxEat NEW\GeauxEat\App_Data\GeauxEatAccessDB.accdb"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I tried making it

```
<add name="dbConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|Data Directory|\GeauxEatAccessDB.accdb"/>
```

but then it looks for something in this folder where it doesn't exist.

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevServer\\10.0"
```

Is there any way to get it relative? It's located in the AppData folder of the project file

Comment: Checkout this link http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007
bookmark this link for future references- http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: thx DJ KRAZE, but I already have the connection string working. I just need to get it to be a relative path or at least change the path of |Data Directory|

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative path reference in WebConfig.ConnectionString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125157/relative-path-reference-in-webconfig-connectionstring)

Comment: but where can I change the path of |DataDirectory| so it doesn't look in
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevServer\\10.0"

but instead look in my App_Data folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked around and got it working. I inserted this line into the Application_Start method of the Global.asax file

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"));
```