# How change location of |DataDirectory| in ASP.NET application built in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datadirectory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a relative path in connection string for Access DB in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169526/using-a-relative-path-in-connection-string-for-access-db-in-c-sharp)

This is my current connection string in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="dbConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\GeauxEatAccessDB.accdb"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

but instead of looking in the App_Data folder, the application looks in

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevServer\\10.0"
```

which isn't right. How and where can I change the default location of |DataDirectory| to be the relative path of App_Data inside the project folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the AppDomain.SetData method to specify where the |DataDirectory| points to:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "YourPath");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @platon, I looked into it a little more and used this line to get it working `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"));`