# OleDb Data Source - Why does it look in this random location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I'm connecting to an access database with OleDb, and the data source is located in my project files. Since the project will be zipped and moved around, I want it to be found no matter what.

```
connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=University.accdb;";
```

Any other time I have worked with a data source, I have been able to put it's location like that, however, when I do that here, it tries to look in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\University.accdb'.

Is there any way I can make this automatically look inside the project files?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your database file in your App_Data directory in your solution.  Then use this for your connection string...

```
connetionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\University.accdb;";
```

`|DataDirectory|` will find your App_Data folder where it's deployed.

**EDIT:** Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186810/2270839) SO post you also need the following line in your Application_Start method of your Global.asax.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"));
```

Comment: This now gives me an "unrecognized escape sequence" error at the \.

Comment: I corrected it... that's standard for C# strings.. you either need the `@` sign to tell it not to use escape sequences or escape a single \ by replacing it with \\.

Comment: @smritz Did my edit above fix the issue?  I edited the line with the connection string.