# Syntax of SQL Server database connection string in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am beginner at SQL and thank you for your attention. I've created a database (by using "Add new Item" from "Project" menu and adding a "Service Based Database") in Visual Studio 2015 and now I want to connect to it and read or write data on it.

But I don't know how to connect to it by code.

I use the string showed in the connection string when I click on the database in server explorer.

That is here:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="c:\users\soroush\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\databasetest2\databasetest2\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

But as you know, it cannot be used when I copy and paste it to a string thah can be used in `new sqlConnection(connection string)`, because this string has '\' or ' " '

What's the right string for me to connect to this local database?

Now this is my code but it is not useful:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = c:\users\soroush\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\databasetest2\databasetest2\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
    con.Open();

    string t=@"INSERT INTO Table (Id,name) Values (34, 'John')";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(t, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = c:\users\soroush\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\databasetest2\databasetest2\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        string t = "SELECT * From Table";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(t, con);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(reader["Id"].ToString() + reader["name"].ToString());
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

**Update**: I get another errors in writing and reading table

I think I've connected to my database after using your help. and now I have another error in reading the table. this error points to

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

in my code and says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

and an error in writing on table points to

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

in my code:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

My database has one table named `Table` that contains two columns: `Id(int)` and `name(nchar10)`

Comment: I tried this for connection string and it didn't worked too:
>"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+"c: \\users\\soroush\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\databasetest2\\databasetest2\\Database1.mdf"+";Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Have you try escaping the `\` with `\\` and the `"` with `\"`?

Comment: Remove the quotes in the string and add a `@` in front of the string: `@"Data Source=...`

Comment: I removed the quotes and add a @ before the string. I think i have connected to database but i have another error. in executing the cmd.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186810/34092 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3501950/34092 . These will show you how to use |Data Directory| in connection strings.

Comment: Show us your updated code @Lionking89 .

Comment: you need to check your strings in the debugger -- non of the strings you have typed here are correct.  In the answer you don't escape `\ ` and in the comment you have `C: \ ` with a space after the colon.

Comment: You probably should remove the quotes around 56 and 34. But you'd need to show us the full exception details to be more helpful than that. Also, please show us the data types of `ID` and `Name` in `table` (can you show us the CREATE TABLE script?).

Comment: I have updated the question whit full code @mjwills 
thank for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
string t = "SELECT * From Table";
```

to:

```
string t = "SELECT * From [Table]";
```

and:

```
string t=@"INSERT INTO Table (Id,name) Values (34, 'John')";
```

to:

```
string t=@"INSERT INTO [Table] (Id,name) Values (34, 'John')";
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/695590/34092 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql .

Answer (score 2):

The code you're using to connect to your SQL database is really old school. We just don't do it like that any more.

So - what can we do instead? Let's use a [nice library called Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) which makes 'talking' to a SQL Server *really easy, simple and safer*.

First, install the package Dapper from Nuget:

[image]

Create a POCO which will represent the data that is returned from the DB.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now update the form code as follows:

```
private const string _connectionString = @"Data Source = (LocalDB) <snipped..>";



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO Table (Id,name) Values (34, 'John')";
    int rowsInserted;
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        rowsInserted = db.Execute(query);
    }

    if (rowsInserted != 1)
    {
        // Log/Handle the fact that you failed to insert 1 record;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList<Foo> foos;

    using (var db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        const string query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
         // This will always return a list. It's empty or has items in it.
        foos = db.Query<Foo>(query).ToList();
    }

    foreach(var foo in foos)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{foo.Id} - {foo.Name}");
    }
}
```

Is that much cleaner? Yep - I thought so.

Of course, I would never put database code behind a winform event but into a dedicated class, etc. But I guess you're just learning/playing around/experimenting :) :)

Also, I've not put error handling in there, to keep the example smallish.

Answer (score 0):

my problem has been solved
at first for connection to database I typed an @ before connection string and deleted the quotes inside the string as @juergen d said in comments

at second for solving the error in writing and reading the table I typed [ and ] before and after the "Table" as @mjwills said

also @Pure.Krome explained a more professional way to improve the code

thank you every body

Comment: Good luck! Also hope you don't get sql-injected.