# Make the connectionstring's AttachDbFilename relative in config file

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, app-config

I am working on a project using an mdf file generated locally using Entity Framework Code First. The path to this mdf is set in several config files in my solution using `<connectionStrings>` sections like so :

`<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;E:\path\to\project\app_data\local.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

I use git versionning on this project both from work and at home, thus at work the mdf filepath has to be `E:\path\to\project\app_data\local.mdf\` and at home  `D:\otherpath\to\project\app_data\local.mdf`.

This is painful to change everytime I comute (first world problem, I know).

I have seen how to set a [substitution string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccess/archive/2005/10/28/486273.aspx) but this seems to be using code outside the config file and I don't want that. Maybe there is a way to set a relative |DataDirectory| value inside the config file ?

Can I make this path relative to a unique place next to my .sln file, using only those config files ?

This would ideally be something like that :

`<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|RelativeToWorkplaceDynamicPath|\local.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative path reference in WebConfig.ConnectionString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125157/relative-path-reference-in-webconfig-connectionstring)

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out how to make this work.

I explain in detail at: [How to embed a database in a visual studio solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185383/how-to-embed-a-database-in-a-visual-studio-solution/25211949#25211949)

In short, you start your connection string with the substitution string "|DataDirectory|". And then you set your current AppDomain's "DataDirectory" setting to where you want it to be, before you access the database.

It's not perfectly clean, but it's workable.