# Not a valid path

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've created an MS Access database file on one PC on which the project is created. When I try to copy the whole project including DB file, an exception comes up saying "c:\path\db.accdb is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path 
name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides." No matter how many times I change the connection string on the other PC.

Following is connection string on PC project is created

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Inventory-Management-System\Data\Inventory.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

and connection string iv'e trying on other PC

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Inventory-Management-System\Data\Inventory.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Comment: Am I correct to say that you are NOT pulling a connectionString from a ConfigFile but are hard-coding it?

Comment: Try using a relative path, see this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125157/relative-path-reference-in-webconfig-connectionstring

Comment: @Sage i think m hard coding it , please tell me how to pull connectionString from ConfigFIle

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to correct this issue. One of the good ones, is what dan said (Relative path). Other ways are using some place, which is not user specific, due to mistakes which could happened here in User path & etc.